# Keep alphanumeric but remove rows with only numbers in R

Tags: r

How do I remove the rows which have only numbers in them.
I have:

```
col A     colB      colc
1947       2            3
1947       USA1        USA
1947       Canada     Canada
1947       NA         Mexico
```

what I want is:

```
col A     colB      colc

1947       USA1        USA
1947       Canada     Canada
1947       NA         Mexico
```

Please note the numerics are present in other rows but i want the rows that have only numerics to be removed(based on `colB` and `colc`)
I tried grep in c("USA1","canada","Mexico") but this removes NA values which I want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

We can loop over the columns, use `grepl` to find the numeric elements, then `Reduce` it to a logical `vector` to subset the rows

```
df1[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1[-1], grepl, pattern = '^[0-9]+$')),]
#   colA   colB   colc
#2 1947   USA1    USA
#3 1947 Canada Canada
#4 1947   <NA> Mexico
```

---

Another option is to convert to `numeric` and then check with `is.na` because all the non-numeric elements will be converted to `NA` with a warning message

```
df1[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1[-1], function(x) is.na(as.numeric(x)))),]
```

Comment: There should be a way on SO to update old answers, for ex: this question would dfntly have better ways to do it now

Comment: @VaibhavSingh You are right and if you have a better option please do post as a solution esp with tidyverse